# Joint probability of two continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I tried solving this problem as part of homework in my class recently and was hoping someone could help me figure out the solution/where I went wrong. The problem is:

There are two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$. They have the joint pdf:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
k(x^2 + y^2) & & 0<x<3,  0<y<3 \\
0 & & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right\}$

$k$ is a positive constant. Find the probability $P(X>2 $ or $ Y>2).$

I integrated over the regions to find that $k= \frac{1}{54}$, but I'm having trouble finding the actual probability. My thought was to use inclusion-exclusion and do the following integral:

$\int_2^3\int_2^3\frac{1}{54}(x^2 + y^2)dx dy $

but after that I'm not quite sure where to go. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclusion/Exclusion will work. It  is easier to find the probability of the complement, that is, the probability that $X$ and $Y$ are both between $0$ and $2$. So our required probability is
$$1-\int_0^2\int_0^2 \frac{1}{54}(x^2+y^2)\,dy\,dx.$$

**Remark:** Inclusion/Exclusion yields
$$\int_{x=0}^3\int_{y=2}^3 k(x^2+y^2)\,dy\,dx+\int_{y=0}^3\int_{x=2}^3 k(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy-\int_2^3\int_2^3 k(x^2+y^2)\,dy\,dx.$$

Comment: Ah, I was overcomplicating it a bunch. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. In the Remark, I gave the more complicated version, $\Pr(2\lt Y\lt 3)+\Pr(2\lt X\lt 3)-\Pr(2\lt Y\lt 3 \cap 2\lt X\lt 3)$.